# How to sort correctly by nested field in Spring JPA Hibernate using Pagination and Sorting?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I have the following entities (short versions):

```
@Entity
class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Builder.Default
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long parentId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String age;
}
```

I'm using Specification Builder.
Note, there are many other fields in the child class, and sorting works for all of them accept for the field which I named "age", for this purpose.

When I try to sort the Parents based on the child's field age, I'm not getting the correct result in case when one Parent have children that are not the same age.

For example:

```
Parent1 = [
Child{
   age: 12
}
Child{
   age: 12
}
Child{
   age: 12
}

],
Parent2 = [
Child{
   age: 5
}
Child{
   age: 5
}
Child{
   age: 5
{
],
Parent3 = [
Child{
   age: 20
}
Child{
   age: 20
}
Child{
   age: 10
{
]
```

The result after sorting is parent2, parent1, parent3, even though parent3 has one child with age of 10.
I would like to get: parent2, parent3, parent1.

I'm wondering is that even possible? I mean the parent3 has 3 children - 2 children has age of 20, and only one age of 10 and I would like for the parent3 to appear before the parent1 because of that. But I can not get it to work.

I thought the issue might be because the age is actually a String, but I have tried with adding the additional field:

```
@Formula(value = "ABS(age)")
private Integer age;
```

But the same result.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but you will need to use window functions for this purpose. With Hibernate 6 you can simply use the following:

```
select p 
from Parent p 
join fetch p.children c 
order by min(c.age) over(partition by p.id)
```